# django-cms identify browser user

Tags: django, django-cms

client html cannot access to sessionid (httpOnly). So I am going to get sessionid by csrf token from server side to identify browser users.

From server (backend) side in which file can I get mapping csrf token with sessionid token ?

Comment: what do you mean by browser user - something like `request.user` ?

Comment: yes. request.user.

Comment: I am using custom html which need to send sessionid over ws. I dont want to play with django-cms code to much. thats why I need to get sessionid is enough for me

Comment: I still don't understand your problem - why don't you simply use `request.user`?

Comment: because I have separate websocket backend. I am not using django, I am using django-cms. So dont want to write additional code to cms. I have backend and this backend will connect to django-cms database to get sessionid. But client side not send sessionid, cliend send only csrf token, i need to understand this csrf token belong to which user .

Comment: If you're using django-cms then you have to be using django, it depends on django. CSRF isn't anything to do with a user. CSRF is a security measure to secure `POST` requests. You cannot use the CSRF token to figure out a user. If a user is logged in, use `request.user` to get the logged in user.